# What is this mysterious filter and purpose?

Tags: hvac

Behind the regular HVAC air filter and next to the duct, there is a filter area with some rough filter covering an additional smaller duct. Does anyone have any idea what it is and its purpose?

[image]

Comment: Perhaps some sort of fresh air intake? Put a speaker up to it and try walking around listening for the other end of it...

Comment: When you put the speaker next to the hole make sure you play some music, i suggest "fixing a hole" by the Beatles.

Comment: The filter media looks similar to the media used in humidifiers. But without any water lines, that is unlikely. (A manually wetted humidifier seems quite impractical.) Is there anything behind the filter?

Comment: Worst case, I mount speaker definitely and get myself a whole home speaker system.

Comment: is the front or the back of the small filter dirtier?

Comment: Can't you just go into your attic and find where it leads to? Is there a fan behind it?

Comment: This doesn't look like it's behind an "HVAC filter"; it just looks like a ceiling return conduit. What do you see if you slide that filter out? I assume it's another conduit; can you tell where it goes? (Another picture of that would be helpful.)

Answer (score 2):

My guess is that you have a high efficiency furnace and they will have a way to get combustion air separately from the regular air stream. The image below depicts this as "combustion air" toward the top.
[image]

In more modern systems the source of that combustion air is a 2nd pipe going outside, so as to not create negative pressure in the living space that ultimately pulls unconditioned air in through cracks and leaks in the walls, doors and windows. Yours may be an earlier version from before they figured that out, so it is taking in the combustion air from the intake grill, but using a filter to keep from introducing dust to the combustion chamber and creating soot. It also means you can change that filter without going outside, so maybe that's deliberate if you live in a cold area.